Can other types of medical imaging be used as verbs like X-ray? Ultrasound, CT/CAT, MRI, PET
There are various forms of medical imaging: X-ray, ultrasound, CT/CAT, MRI, PET.
X-ray can be used as a verb ("they X-rayed my broken leg"), but can any of the others? They all sound strange to me (and ambiguous for "the oncologist wanted to PET the patient's breasts").
Can I say "the urologist ultrasounded my kidneys"?

It's not the idiomatic expression, which is did an ultrasound on, performed an ultrasound on.

I think the verbs you are looking for are probably image and scan, eg the urologist scanned my kidneys ultrasonically or the doctor imaged the patient's tumour with a PET scanner. No time to write a proper answer or to support these suggestions with citations etc.

I think you can say they "PET-scanned".

You can check dictionaries to see if they list the terms as verbs; that gives some guidance on whether it's a common usage. It also depends on tone/register: informally "ultrasounded" would be easily understandable, but if it's not in a dictionary it might not pass in formal writing.

Verbing is a well-known phenomenon, which has been addressed numerous times on this site. It is not clear why the verbing of medical-imaging terms would need to be discussed separately (except perhaps for PET, in so far as pet already exists as a verb with an entirely unrelated meaning).

Dictionaries lag behind new usage.
Ultrasound can be found as a verb in the scientific literature written by native speakers, so depending on your level of comfort and, perhaps, your audience, I don't see why you can't use it. Other examples of verbs that began as compound nouns for methods and equipment are seismograph, polygraph and fluoroscope.
Examples:

... ovaries were ultrasounded in one-half of the heifers to
measure ovarian length and height...
Sherrill Echternkamp et al.; "Effect of Dietary Energy on Ovarian Development and Fertility in Postpuberal Beef Heifers"  (2010)


One thousand eight hundred and six infants were ultrasounded, 6.3% of
the birth population.
R.W. Paxton et al.; "CAN A TARGETED ULTRASOUND
SCREENING PROGRAMME FOR DEVELOPMENTAL DYSPLASIA OF THE HIP BE JUSTIFIED ON A NATIONAL BASIS? RESULTS OF AN 8-YEAR PROSPECTIVE PROJECT" (2024)

You can search in Google Scholar or Pub Med to see the usage.

I agree that "X-rayed" sounds much more acceptable than "ultrasounded," though Wiktionary does provide a definition of ultrasound as a verb and you can find occasional attestations online.
That aside, there is a reason for this discrepancy. As CGEL notes (p. 1642), while compound nouns (like blacklist) can be freely converted to verbs, nouns that are derivatives--essentially, ones consisting of a prefix or suffix attached to a base--tend to resist that sort of conversion. Since "ultra-" is one such prefix, one would indeed expect "ultrasound" to be unlikely to undergo conversion into a verb.
I'm not sure if there's any general principle regarding when acronyms like "MRI" can be converted into verbs, though to me "The doctor MRIed the patient" sounds substantially better than "The doctor ultrasounded the patient."
